# Arduino RGB IR Controller -> led always close to white

Tags: arduino-nano, rgb-led, remote-control

I use arduino nano.

When i use this code the rgb light on the fan is showing the colors right

`int rossoPin = 11;
int verdePin = 12;
int bluPin = 10;
void setup(){
  pinMode(rossoPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(verdePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);
}
void loop(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    rgb(255-i, i, 0);
    delay(10);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    rgb(0, 255-i, i);
    delay(10);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
    rgb(i, 0, 255-i);
    delay(10);
  }
}
void rgb(int red, int green, int blue){
  analogWrite(rossoPin, red);
  analogWrite(verdePin, green);
  analogWrite(bluPin, blue);
}`

,but when i use the full controller code it wont work nothing(ex.white color when it's on off state)

FULL CODE: 
[link to the code](https://pastebin.com/ajJC615g)

Comment: Your code is for a single RGB LED or a simple dump RGB LED strip.  The linked code is for a NeoPixel (WS2812B) strip. Which are you using?

Comment: The controller is for an a-rgb strip and I want to control also a single rgb led on a fan, so i have added the function void fanON() which has the above code that works separatly

Comment: Does the IR code get correctly received? Honestly I don't want to analyse over 700 lines of code. You should deactivate parts of your code, until you found the problematic code

Comment: in the setup i call the function rgb(0, 0, 0); and it supposed to turn off the led when i start the arduino without any input, but the led is showing white. And yes the IR get correctly received. When i press on my ir remote the strip changes color but the led on the fan no->still white